# Is $\sum_{k=1}^{\log n}2^ke^{-\beta (2^k-1)}$ bounded by a constant?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Is the following upper bounded by a constant (possibly dependent on $\beta > 0$)?
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\log n}2^ke^{-\beta (2^k-1)}
$$
**My Approach:** I'm thinking of bounding the sum with $\int 2^x e^{-\beta(2^x-1)}dx$, but don't know how exactly to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: consider using the root test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "substitution" $j=2^k$, notice that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}2^ke^{-\beta(2^k-1)} < \sum_{j=2}^{n}je^{-\beta (j-1)}$$

since the summation you have only "samples" the terms in the rightmost summation that were powers of $2$. Therefore your sum is bounded by geometric series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}2^ke^{-\beta(2^k-1)} < \frac{d}{d x}\left(\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\right)\Biggr|_{x=e^{-\beta}}-1$$